# CS0104: ambiguous reference between 'System.Numerics.Vector3' and 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I am not able to use Vector3 in my code.

> error : Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0104  'Vector3' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Numerics.Vector3' and 'UnityEngine.Vector3' Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\BJ\Documents\New Unity Project (1)\Assets\move.cs  9   Active

Comment: You seem to have a `using System.Numerics` somewhere at the top of your file (cut off in your screenshot)

Comment: Please don't post images of code - review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a using directive for `System.Numerics` and one for `UnityEngine`.  Both of those namespaces contain a `Vector3`.  So you'll have to decide which one you mean.

You can fully qualify the type like this to resolve the ambiguity:

```
UnityEngine.Vector3 move; // Probably this is what you meant, I'm guessing
```

...or...

```
System.Numerics.Vector3 move;
```

...depending on which one you intended.

You can also remove the `using` statement for the unwanted namespace.  For example, if you don't want the `using` directive for `System.Numerics`, then remove the line that looks like:

```
using System.Numerics;
```

This will force you to fully qualify any other types from `System.Numerics` that you may have used elsewhere, but then you can just say `Vector3 move;` and it will unambiguously resolve to `UnityEngine.Vector3`.

Comment: There's no real surprises here.  This answer could literally be used as an improved template for the CS0104 error message.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using conflicting namespaces, check the `using` directives at the top of your code, you haven't provided the complete code so I'm not sure, but if you're using both `UnityEngine` and `System` namespaces in your code, use fully qualified type names

Answer (score -1):

add `using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;` above could also be a solution. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om7hq.png)

Comment: No screenshots of text please. Post text as text with [formatting](/help/formatting)