# I just want to do a SIMPLE horizontal movement and i have no idea at all what am doing wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;

public class cc2d : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float movementspeed = 100f;
    float hmovement;
    float vmovement;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        hmovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vmovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");      
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (hmovement > 0f || hmovement<-0f)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(hmovement * movementspeed,0,0),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

The errors are (in unity debug itself and not in visual studio)

> Assets\scripts\cc2d.cs(24,29): error CS0104: 'Vector2' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and 'System.Numerics.Vector2'

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030512/cs0104-ambiguous-reference-between-system-numerics-vector3-and-unityengine-v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file uses both `System.Numerics` and `UnityEngine`, both of which define a type called `Vector2`, so the compiler gets confused.
The solution? Either get rid of `using System.Numerics` as you don't seem to be using it anywhere or replace `Vector2` with `UnityEngine.Vector2` to explicitly tell the compiler that you want the `Vector2` from `UnityEngine` and not `System.Numerics`
Option 1: Exactly as you have it right now, but without the `using System.Numerics;` at the top
Option 2: (not recommended as Unity types are needed often) replace every instance of `Vector2` with `UnityEngine.Vector2`

Comment: thankyou so much(also i was adding three arguments where vector2 has only two argument lol)

Comment: No problem! Please consider marking my answer as accepted (tickmark under score counter)

Answer (score 2):

Delete `using System.Numerics;` in your script.

You just want to use the `UnityEngine.Vector2` Vector.

Comment: Can you show the line, where the error appears?